# Find how much substance is formed in 4 minutes if the rate of formation is given by the function $f(t) = 9 - \frac{1}{2}t^2$

Tags: calculus

> In a chemical reaction two substances are combining to form a third
>   one. The rate  at which the third substance is being formed in
>   grams/min is given by the function $f(t) = 9 - \frac{1}{2}t^2$ when
>   the reaction has been underway for $t$ minutes. How much substance is
>   formed in $4$ minutes?

I suppose that to answer that question, we need to integrate $f(t)$:
$$\int f(t) dt = 9t -  \frac{1}{6}t^3 + C$$

I believe we can assume there that $C = 0$

Plugging 4 in:
$$9(4) - \frac{1}{6}(4)^3 \approx 25.3\text{ gram}$$

However, the textbook says that the answer is $\frac{1}{3}$ gram.

What have I done wrong? And if I am wrong, how to solve the problem above?

Comment: Strictly speaking you should calculate $F(4)-F(0)$ where $F$ is whatever antiderivative you like. You just chose $C$ such that $F(0)=0$. In any case I don't see the mistake.

Comment: In the first minute alone, the rate is always more than 8, so there have to be at least 8 grams formed. It seems to me that the question as written can't have answer $\frac 13$